# Python xml elem.text.replace(original, today) works inconsitenly

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I'm trying to overwrite two date tag.text in an xml, with the "xml.etree.Elementree as ET". (Our companies user account control does not allow lxml, for some reason.)

Expected result:

```
date1: #DATE#T07:05:07Z        ==> 2021-01-07T07:05:07Z
date2: #DATE#T07:06:00+01:00   ==> 2021-01-07T07:06:00+01:00
```

Here is my code:

```
def kwt():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    today = datetime.date.today().day
    kwt_dt = now + datetime.timedelta(days=int(today), hours=1)
    date = kwt_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+01:00')
    return date
today = kwt()

with open(path_for_slup, "r+") as slup:
    slup_tree = ET.parse(path_for_slup)
    slup_root = slup_tree.getroot()
    for elem in slup_root.iter():
        if str(elem.text).__contains__("#DATE#"):
            try:
                old_elememt_text = elem.text
                print("Old elem.text:", elem.text)
                elem.text = elem.text.replace("#DATE#", today)
                print("New elem.text:", elem.text)
                new_elememt_text = elem.text
            except:
                print("There is a problem with overwriting the #DATE#")
                print("Old elem.text:", type(elem.text))
```

Actual result:

1. case with the use of today = datetime.date.today()

```
Old elem.text: #DATE#
There is a problem with overwriting the #DATE#
Old elem.text: <class 'str'>

Old elem.text: #DATE#T07:06:00+01:00
There is a problem with overwriting the #DATE#
Old elem.text: <class 'str'>
```

2. case: with the use of the kwt() function

```
Old elem.text: #DATE#
New elem.text: 2021-01-14T

Old elem.text: #DATE#T07:06:00+01:00
New elem.text: 2021-01-14TT07:06:00+01:00

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There are several things I do not get:

1. case:
   a. I use the same code for both #DATE# exchanges, but the first time it recognises that "old elem.text" should be just #DATE# and the second time it does not. Why?
   b. What kind of problem could elem.text.replace() have that it can't replace the #DATE# with the var today?
2. case:
   a. same as 1.case a.
   b. At the first #DATE# the whole tag text was replaced, at the second only the #DATE# part was replaced. Again, why?

Example XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <slupClient:SLUP>
            <tagname1>1</tagname1>
            <tagname2>XXX</tagname2>             
            <tagname3>#DATE#T07:05:07Z</tagname3>  <!-- T07:05:07Z -->
            .
            .
            .
            <tagname20>
                <tagname>ABC</tagname>  
                <val>#DATE#T07:06:00+01:00</val>   <!--T07:06:00+01:00-->
            </tagname20>
```

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you can not replace a string ('#DATE#') by a datetime object (your `datetime.date.today()` here).

You have to format this date object into a string, and that's actually the job of the `.strftime('format')` method you use inside your kwt function.

What means you could do this for example (I simplified your code a little):

```
data = ["#DATE#T07:05:07Z", "#DATE#T07:06:00+01:00"]

today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for text in data:
    if "#DATE#" in text:
        text_init = text
        text = text.replace("#DATE#", today)
        print(text_init, " => ", text)
```

This should answer to your question 1.b

Questions 1.a and 1.b

You're processing every element that *contains* the string '#DATE#', which is the case for your two strings ("#DATE#" and "#DATE#T07:06:00+01:00"). There is nothing wrong here, since I suppose one of the elements in your xml file contains only the string "#DATE#"?

Question 2.b

I don't get it? In your second case, the first string was "#Date#", so it's pretty normal the full string is replaced, don't you think?

Comment: @olinix: Thank you for the answer. You are right about, the datetime. On the other hand if you see the xml part I attached, both are #DATE#+Something extra, and here I checked and both are string. That is why my confusion. 
<tagname3>#DATE#T07:05:07Z</tagname3>
and
<val>#DATE#T07:06:00+01:00</val>.
Thank you for the code, I never saw that before. Seems simpler, I will try it out.

Comment: Yeah I saw the xml you mentionned, but I assumed it was not the complete file is it? are you sure there is no node in your file whom text is only "#DATE#?

Comment: olinox14: yeah, quite sure :).
Since then I solved the problem with a work around, but I still don't get why is it behaving in differently for the two #DATE#. Plus I have another #SOMETHING#_PLUSPART text in the XML, where it functions properly. Python is fun, fun, fun :D